# Execution order of uGUI events in Unity?

Tags: unity, gui, events

I'm trying to understand how UI events fit into the overall Unity update loop. Specifically, I want to manually call `onClick` via script, and then modify the effect of that event within the same frame.

The button disables and enables some objects on click, but I can't find those objects (via `transform.Find`) immediately after `myButton.onClick.Invoke()`. They don't appear until the next frame. Yet, if I add a `Debug.Break` after this frame, the new objects are rendered to the screen. So it clearly doesn't take an extra frame for the `onClick` event to occur.

The question is, when exactly does `onClick` happen? And can I write code that does something after `onClick` but before the frame is rendered?